# startActivityForResult sends data, but the returned Intent contains no data

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass data to a TestActivity, then return new data back when finished.

Basically, MainActivity puts data into an Intent and starts an ActivityForResult. This TestActivity displays the data in a TextView and clicking a button adds new data to a new Intent and sends the user back to the MainActivity.
Back in MainActivity, onActivityResult executes which should contain the new data.

The data contained in the Intent passes fine TO the TestActivity, but I can't seem to find the new data returning back to MainActivity. I keep getting a NullPointException:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference.

Thanks for the help!

Here is the MainActivity:

```
// Define the StartActivityForResult and the ActivityResultCallback
ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult testStartActivityForResult = new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult();
ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult> testActivityResultCallback = new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {

    // This code executes after the testActivity is complete
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Intent test2Intent = result.getData();      // Empty.
            //Intent test2Intent = getIntent();         // I tried getIntent, but that is also empty.

            Bundle test2Bundle = test2Intent.getExtras(); //NullPointerException

            User test2User = (User) test2Bundle.getSerializable(USER_KEY); //

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, test2User.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

// Here I create my testLauncher and fill a Bundle with data
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> testLauncher = registerForActivityResult(testStartActivityForResult, testActivityResultCallback);
Bundle testBundle = new Bundle();
testBundle.putSerializable(USER_KEY, new User("TestUserName"));
Intent testIntent = new Intent(this, TestActivity.class);
testIntent.putExtras(testBundle);

// Launch the testActivity
testLauncher.launch(testIntent);
```

Here is the TestActivity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView testTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Button testButton = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        testTextView = findViewById(R.id.testTextView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        User testUser = (User)intent.getSerializableExtra(USER_KEY);
        testTextView.setText(testUser.getUsername());

        testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                User test2User = new User("test2Username");
                Bundle test2Bundle = new Bundle();
                test2Bundle.putSerializable(USER_KEY, test2User);
                intent.putExtras(test2Bundle);
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is a simplification of my custom object, serialized for passing through Intents:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private String username;

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending back the `intent` data to `MainActivity` because you have not set "intent" value to `setResult` method

Replace

```
intent.putExtras(test2Bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

with

```
intent.putExtras(test2Bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
```